# Count the total sub nodes in a JSON using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to find the count of the total nodes inside a file which is in JSON format. I tried the below code and it is not working. Googled few but couldn't find what I am looking for. I am new to JSON file handling, please guide me.

**Json Input 1:**

```
    {
        "CandidateId": "E3",
        "Ngocentre": "Chennai",
        "FirstName": "XXX",
        "LastName": "YYY",
        "PhoneNumber": 22221,
        "EmailId": "E3@gmail.com",
        "EducationalQualification": "Graduate",
        "SkillSet": "ASP.NET",
        "CreatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "UpdatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "NgoemailId": "gurukul@gmail.com"
    }
```

** Json Input 2:**

```
    [
    {
        "CandidateId": "E3",
        "Ngocentre": "Chennai",
        "FirstName": "XXX",
        "LastName": "YYY",
        "PhoneNumber": 22221,
        "EmailId": "E3@gmail.com",
        "EducationalQualification": "Graduate",
        "SkillSet": "ASP.NET",
        "CreatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "UpdatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "NgoemailId": "gurukul@gmail.com"
    },
        {
        "CandidateId": "E3",
        "Ngocentre": "Chennai",
        "FirstName": "XXX",
        "LastName": "YYY",
        "PhoneNumber": 22221,
        "EmailId": "E3@gmail.com",
        "EducationalQualification": "Graduate",
        "SkillSet": "ASP.NET",
        "CreatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "UpdatedByNgo": "Gurukul",
        "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "NgoemailId": "gurukul@gmail.com"
    }
    ]
```

My ideal output should be "1" for the 1st input and "2" for the 2nd input. I tried the below code.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Read.txt"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                int count = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)source).Root).Count;
            }
```

But when pass only the 1st input, I am getting count as 13 which is the total properties inside a Json.
Above code piece returns 2 for the 2nd input which is the ideal output, but it fails when I pass 1st input alone.

Comment: if you have a tree-like datastructure, would you expect to return only the top nodes or nested nodes as well?

Comment: @draz, just the top nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just count the tokens :

```
    if (json.StartsWith("["))
    {
        // If the json is an array
        var array = JArray.Parse(json);
        Console.WriteLine(array.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the json is only one object, the result is 1.
        // I added a way to retieve the object as token array :
        var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var tokens = jobject.SelectTokens("$"); // You can go through you object : jobject.SelectTokens("$.CandidateId") => "E3"
        Console.WriteLine(tokens.Count());
    }
```

An other solution would be the Regex with atomic group.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the array manually is overkill, you just need to parse a `JArray` out of it.

```cs
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Read.txt"))
{
    var array = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JArray>(r);
    Console.WriteLine(array.Count);
}
```